# Variable is undefined after adding a 'while statement' and list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, spyder

I am creating a Hangman guessing game/machine. I know it's been done a million times before but I'm just starting out in python so I'm trying to figure out how to do it without having the answer thrown in my face.

I had initially copied the code out 7 times, was going to continue with an if statement up to 11 but with my VBA experience I thought I would try make it semi-smart even if it is only version 1 by adding a `while` loop in. (Plan for v2 is to add a bit of intelligence in, possibly a dictionary to cross reference/calculate letter frequencies etc. but just a pipe dream until version 1 is finished)

Basically the code was working fine when it was repeating but once I added the while loop in it first failed due to `lnG1` and `pos` not being defined. So I added a list to define the values as 0 or "" even though they are being overwritten.

```
import random
lcGuess = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
lnLife = 7
lcWord = 'a'
while (len(lcWord)!=5):
  try:
    lcWord = str(input("""Fancy a game of Hangman? Pick a 5 letter word, I have 7 wrong guesses to 
    try figure it out \n """))
  except:
    print('5 letter words only')

 lcClean = lcWord.lower()
 tokens = list(lcClean)
 maxVal = 25

 x = 1

 lnG1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]
 pos1 = ["","","","",""]
 pos2 = ["","","","",""]
 pos3 = ["","","","",""]
 pos4 = ["","","","",""]
 pos5 = ["","","","",""]
 maxChar = 0

while lnLife > 1:
  g = random.randint(0,maxVal)
  lnG1[x] = lcGuess[g]
  print('My 1st guess is ' + str(lnG1[x]))
  if lnG1[x] in tokens:
     print('I guessed right ' + lnG1[x] + ' is in your word \n')
     maxChar = lcClean.count(lnG1[x])
  if maxChar >= 1:
    pos1[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x])
  if maxChar >= 2:
    pos2[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x], pos1[x] + 1)
  if maxChar >= 3:
    pos3[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x], pos2[x] + 1)
  if maxChar >= 4:
    pos4[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x], pos3[x] + 1)
  if maxChar >= 5:
    pos5[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x], pos4[x] + 1)

  if lnG1[x] not in tokens:
    lnLife = lnLife - 1
    print('I guessed wrong ' + lnG1[x] + ' is not in your word, I have ' + 
    str(lnLife) + ' lives left 
    \n')

   del lcGuess[g]
   maxVal = maxVal - 1
   x = x + 1
```

So I thought the creating the list would fix it but now I am getting `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` at this line of code: `pos1[x] = lcClean.find(lnG1[x])`
Obviously don't get the error when all of the guesses are wrong.

The way I read it is pos1[1] should be = "" and is about to be replaced by the number of correct letters in the word

Apologies for how long winded this is.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite understanding why `lnG1` and `pos1...5` are lists...

Comment: I need to be able to reference it once I have guessed the 5 correct letters, lnG1 is used to store the guess of the letter and pos obviously returns the index position of that letter in the word (so it can spell the word back once finished)

Comment: Or did you know that and you're referring to not referencing the letters by position or the letters from previous loops and just have a counter once 5 correct answers have been reached then stop and say the word?

Comment: The code below `while lnLife > 1:` is improperly (read: not at all) indented.

Comment: I have edited it, everything under the while statement is indented

Comment: I was thinking that you could just have a single list `word` with five elements (one for each letter) instead of five different lists

Comment: `x` is 5, but there are only 5 elements in the lists you're indexing.  Legal indices are 0-4.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in line x=1. Your lists are zero-indexed in Python, so you should set initial value of x to 0.